# Class getting instantiated implicitly in Angular component class

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Using [angular-material](https://material.angular.io/) (v6), and Typescript in an Angular (v6) app, I'm confused by its behavior and think I might be looking at this too close. Basic code looks like this:

```
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
console.log(BreakpointObserver); // logs the class
@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {
  private breakpointObserver : BreakpointObserver;
  constructor (breakpointObserver : BreakpointObserver) {
    console.log(breakpointObserver); // logs an instance
  }
}
```

I searched through the Angular, angular-material, and Typescript docs to try to find the reasoning for how/where/why the `BreakpointObserver` class is getting instantiated and being passed as a parameter to the `constructor`. Is this a bug?

Comment: Sorry about that! I misread the code. I think you should be getting the Class printed on the console for the console.log inside the constructor. Don't confuse it for an instance. Have a look at its type. It may have a __proto__ which might eventually also have the methods that you were expecting on it. But again, it's a class and not an instance.

Comment: I just spent the last hour debugging this and came to some interesting conclusions! I'll try to outline the cause as best as possible.

Comment: I ended up posting my previous comment, and then seconds later finding the appropriate section in the docs! I had debugged the framework and found an interesting switch statement which auto-instantiates factory services. https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/183757daa28e575bd9ffb8ae6c31ebee7ff45443/packages/core/src/view/provider.ts#L245

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a function of standard "Angular DI." [Here](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#inject-a-service) is the reference to this specific behavior in the Angular docs.